# How can we setup pkg-config for cimgui to use it with meson to build our project?

Tags: c, cmake, pkg-config, meson-build, imgui

My question is primarily two parts:

I have tried to install Cimgui from their [github](https://github.com/cimgui/cimgui) page. I first clone the project and its subprojects like imgui as said in their page. Then, after running `make` and `sudo cmake --install . --config Debug`, It builds the project and it adds a `cimgui.so` file to my `/usr/local/` directory. But, I can't figure out how to use it in my projects and specially how to use pkg-config for it. I guess, we are suppose to manually create .pc files but I am not sure how to do it.

Also, please let me know, how I can include it with meson. I know that in meson we can just use cmake but I am not completely sure how I should do it.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Imgui doesn't seem to install `.pc` files, so it is not possible to use it via `pkg-config`. You need to use meson's machinery for locating headers and libraries.

Comment: @arrowd I tried using meson with cmake but it needs cimgui.wrap. Would it be ok just to search for all `.h` and `.c` files to include them?

Comment: cmake is only needed to build `cimgui`. use meson's facilities to find it once it's been installed. you may be better served filing a [new issue](https://github.com/cimgui/cimgui/issues/new) asking for meson support

Comment: Maybe [compiler.find_library()](https://mesonbuild.com/Reference-manual_returned_compiler.html#compilerfind_library) ?

Comment: @droptop Thanks, I did not know this. I will definitely try.

Comment: @nega I put the issue [here](https://github.com/cimgui/cimgui/issues/247) and there was a response which I do not understand!

Answer (score 0):

With `cimgui.so` in `/usr/local` this should work

```
cc = meson.get_compiler('c')
cimgui_dep = cc.find_library('cimgui', dirs: '/usr/local', required: true)
```